# Can the pumping length ever be equal to $0$ ? (Pumping lemma for regular languages)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I have seen some very conflicting information regarding the minimum pumping length.

(part of the) Pumping lemma states :
$\forall$ words $s\in L$ where $|s| > p$

Is it possible to use this expression instead ? :
$\forall$ words $s \in L$ where $|s| > 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Formal_statement) starts with *there exists $p \geqslant 1$ such that for all words in $L$ of  length at least $p$ ...* Thus, you first have to find the appropriate $p$. Depending on $L$, it may happen to be $1$, but $p = 1$ will not work for all regular languages.